# How to refresh dataSource in MatTable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, mat-table

I have a component which have mat-table with data from backend. In this component I have another which is a form for add new element in this data.

It works fine, I can show data in the table, I can add element but after add element my table doesn't refresh data.

Here is my code:

add word:

```js
addWord(): void {
const value = this.addWordForm.value;
console.log(value)
this.wordService.create(value).subscribe(
  (word: Word)  => {
    console.info('Word added');
  },
  (error: Error) =>  {
    console.error(error);
  }
);


create(data: Word): Observable<Word> {
return this.http.post<Word>(this.baseUrl, data);
```

dataSource:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.wordService.getAll().subscribe(
  (data: Word[]): void => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);


getAll(): Observable<Word[]> {
return this.http.get<Word[]>(this.baseUrl);
```

HTML table:

```html
<app-add-word></app-add-word>
<div class="dictionary-table">
  <table #table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{dataSource?.filteredData.indexOf(element) + 1}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Polish Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="polish">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Polski </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.polish}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Spanish Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="spanish">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hiszpański </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.translated}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Type Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Typ </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.type}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
  <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: After adding an element (call create(data: Word)), do you call getAll() ?

Comment: Thx @sankasanjeewa. I needed to pass my dataSource for ma Add-word component and then call getAll and overwrite dataSource.data like that:
`addWord(): void {
    const value = this.addWordForm.value;
    this.wordService.create(value).subscribe(
      ()  => {
        this.wordService.getAll().subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data)
      },
      (error: Error) =>  {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }`

Comment: welcome friend... :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the table optimizes for performance, it will not automatically check for changes to the data array. Instead, when objects are added, removed, or moved on the data array, you can trigger an update to the table's rendered rows by calling its renderRows() method.

```
// In your component
@ViewChild('table') myTable: MatTable<your type>;
.
.
.
// Call this inside wordService.create() success callback
this.myTable.renderRows();
```

Comment: It doesnt work :/ Or I'm doing something wrong. I needed to call getAll() in while adding new element.

Comment: According to me it will work without the need of calling getAll()